# Hierarchical Gridview RegisterRequiresViewStateEncryption error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, gridview

HI I'm trying to create a Hierarchical Gridview following this url http://www.dotnettwitter.com/2011/06/hierarchical-gridview-in-aspnet.html
when I run the sample I keep getting this exception

***The RegisterRequiresViewStateEncryption() method needs to be called before or during Page_PreRender.***

when i remove the child gridview the error goes away "GridViewDetails"
is there anyway to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

oddly enough i just removed this extra code

```
CellSpacing="1" CellPadding="0" GridLines="Both" DataKeyNames="OrderId"
                            BackColor="White" BorderWidth="2px" BorderStyle="Ridge"
                            BorderColor="White" AllowPaging="false" ForeColor="#000066"
```

and things started working. Another post i read sayd it could be the DataKeyNames